# in zsh shell I try to run this command

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro ~ % source ~/.bashrc
/Users/Administrator/.bashrc:49: parse error near `then'
Administrators-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

```
if [ ! -d "${HOME}/.m2" ]; then
        echo "WARN: Maven local repository directory does not exist, creating at ${HOME}/.m2"
        mkdir ${HOME}/.m2
    fi
```

**`49:  if [ ! -d "${HOME}/.m2" ]; then`**

my os details
macOS big sur
version 11.5.1
startup disk Macintosh HD
Graphics Intel Iris Pro

Comment: zsh and bash are two different shells, and they aren't mutually compatible. It's not normal to expect bash code to work in zsh unless it was intentionally written to work with both shells.

Comment: That said, the code you provided should work in both. If your file has hidden characters (like DOS newlines), that could explain a syntax error here (`$'then\r'` -- which is to say, `then` with a CRLF sequence instead of a LF after it -- is not the same as `then`).

Comment: Can you build a [mre] that reproduces the bug when run by someone else?

Comment: (Also, note that a parse error is often caused by content on preceding lines, so if you just take the code between your `if` and your `fi` and put it in a new file, that file may not have any problem at all. Make sure the code in your question here is actually complete enough to cause the bug when run on its own).